# Timeout on scraping KBB car info using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate my car search using python and I'm running into an issue with selenium. Here's a copy of the code I'm working with:

```
def get_kbb_price(mileage, vin, zip_code='90210'):
    options = ChromeOptions()
    
    ua = UserAgent()
    user_agent = ua.random
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    
    driver = Chrome(executable_path='F:\\Program Files (x86)\\ChromeWebDriver\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

    driver.get('https://www.kbb.com/whats-my-car-worth/')
    
    random_delay()

    # Fill in the VIN
    vin_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-lean-auto="vinInput"]')
    vin_input.send_keys(vin)
    
    random_delay()
    
       # Wait for the "Go" button to be clickable and click it
    go_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-lean-auto="vinSubmitBtn"]'))
    )
    go_button.click()

        # Continuously click the "go" button and check the URL, with a 30 second timeout
    start_time = time.time()
    while driver.current_url == 'https://www.kbb.com/whats-my-car-worth/':
        if time.time() - start_time > 30:
            raise Exception("Timed out while waiting for Go button")
        go_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

It seems that only sometimes can I use the "Go" button on the KBB website to continue past the VIN number input and to the mileage page. I'm not sure if KBB has some sort of anti-scraping software that stops my script from clicking the "Go" button. My random delay is between 1 and 3 seconds.

The script tries clicking the "Go" button every second after filling the VIN number until the page is changed to the mileage and zip-code page. I expected this to work as maybe the "Go" button would be unavailable the first try but this hasn't worked.